# Javascript Key Mapping for number

Tags: javascript, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I made a shortcut in my website

```
alt + 1 = something()
alt + 2 = something()
shift + 1 = something()
...

window.addEventListner("keydown",(e) => {
if(e.key === 1 && e.alt) doSomething(); 
})
```

But the problem is when i press `shift+1` it become `shift + !` the key become special char! And alt(option) + 1 is `¡`
Should i make a `Key Map` for every special chars?   Or is there good other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) property and look for the string `"Digit1"`. That's the purpose of `code`, to give you a key name unaffected by modifier keys.

Here's a demo of the difference:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown",(e) => {
    console.log(`key = ${e.key}, code = ${e.code}`);
});
```

```html
Click here, then press 1, and then press !.
```

So for instance:

```
if (e.altKey && e.code === "Digit1") {
    // ...
}
```

(Note that it's [`altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey), not `alt`, to see if the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is down.)